# Modal ao acessar o site

Tags: jquery, modal

Alguém poderia me passar um código simples de jquery?
Só preciso que um modal ( div ) apareça quando o site for acessado e contenha um botão "fechar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Com jquery**

```js
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    
     <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                 <p>Bla bla bla</p>
                 <p class="text-warning"><small>blablabla</small></p>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**Basicamente criada com CSS.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $("#openModal").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
 .modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 }

 .close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 }

 .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
 <div>
  <a href="#" class="close" title="Close">X</a>
  <h2>Janela Modal</h2>
  <p>Esta é uma simples janela de modal.</p>
  <p>Você pode fazer qualquer coisa aqui, página de Login, pop-ups, ou formulários</p>
 </div>
</div>
```